# Is this misprint at 2.5.8 example from [NIST SP800-22 Revision 1a.]?

Tags: random, precision, nist

I am reading the paper, NIST SP800-22 Revision 1a, which is about Randomness Test suite.

This is the [link](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf) where I found, and read.

I **summarized my question at the end of post**. And below description is how my deduction drawn. And also, I haven't found misprint about 2.5.8 Example yet.

### 2.5.4 Test Description

[image: chi_square]

χ^2 is calculated as above equation.

### 2.5.8 Example

[image: Examples]

It is very nice of Example to show all variables. But, sadly, I cannot get χ^2 = 1.2619656 as expected. And I think this is misprint of this paper.

### the reason why I think misprint

1. I got `χ^2 = 1.262580416458114`
2. I double-checked whether my code is wrong with golang `new(big.Float).SetPrec(500)`
3. I triple-checked with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) which is online equation calculator as below captured image.

[image: wolframalpha]

## Question

1. Am I wrong?
2. If I wrong, what is the reason why I cannot get precise answer?
   (I don't think this is precision problem of floating-point or just simple mistake)
3. If this is misprint, how can I report this?
4. Or, 4 decimal places error, `1.262580416458114 - 1.2619656 = 0.000614...`, is **within the margin of error** in the system of Randomness-test?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this does not look related to programming

Comment: @NicoHaase Well.. NIST SP800-22 paper is about Randomness test suite within programming. Isn't it un-related?

Comment: To me, this looks like a math problem - or is there any code involved you want to share?